# Efficient way to check if 2 columns of DataFrame are subsets of each other

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, set

I have 2 DataFrames which has a column whose value is of type **set** containing 8 digit integers.

---

df1 (contains around 200k rows)

```
    id  s1
0   0   {43649632, 95799329, 40649644, 23335890, 81779...
1   1   {69900026, 74441229}
2   2   {85195648, 55750338, 98936902, 82000264, 43544...
3   3   {21916700, 13627806}
4   4   {62929026, 38592365, 44179790, 38355127}
```

---

df2 (contains around 900k rows)

```
    id  s1
0   0   {58209736, 25405713, 28691898, 94682562}
1   1   {81089732, 82343077}
2   2   {59692896, 33234306, 40445479, 18728345, 24464...
3   3   {71406042, 69900026, 74441229}
4   4   {62929026}
```

I want to know the **FASTEST** way to find the pair of `id`s from `df2` and `df2` that match **ONE OF THIS** condition:

- `df1.s1` is a subset of `d2.s1`

**OR**

- `df2.s1` is a subset of `d1.s1`

For example,

- id=1 of df1 is a subset of id=3 of df2, so (1, 3) is a valid pair
- id=4 of df2 is a subset of id=4 of df1, so (1, 4) is a valid pair

---

I have tried this code below but it's going to take about 20 hours:

```
id_pairs = []

for i in tqdm(list(df2.itertuples(index=False))):
    for j in df1.itertuples(index=False):
        if i.s1.issubset(j.s1) or j.s1.issubset(i.s1):
            id_pairs.append((i.id, j.id))
```

Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cartesian join and then apply the condition

```
df1["key"] = 0
df2["key"] = 0

merged = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on="key")

def subset(row):
    if (row.s1.issubset(row.s2)) or (row.s2.issubset(row.s1)):
        return (row.id1, row.id2)
    else:
        return None

merged.apply(lambda row: subset(row), axis=1).dropna()
```